# Phantom jack detected in front panel

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, alsa, hardware-detection

On my PC, dual boot (Windows, Linux) I have an annoying problem: from time to time (like every 15 seconds) my system(both windows, and Manjaro) detect the insertion of jack in the front panel. It also happened on my previous PC, always dual boot but with Ubuntu. This is quite annoying since if I don't disable jack detection(in windows with realtek drivers, and on Linux with some magic), the sound stop playing for a millisecond(because it switches from headphones to speaker).

I can't understand if a hardware problem (because it happens on both OSes) or it's a software problem since it happen because it's a dual boot system(https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1dydtz/linuxwindows_dual_boot_audio_problem/).

The problem get even worse on Linux if I do a reboot of windows instead of a shut down the machine and boot with Linux.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058328/ubuntu-18-04-audio-problem

To be clear on both OS I found a way to mitigate the problem (no pop-up on windows for jack detection and audio interruption, and no audio interruption on Linux).
Uninstalling one of the Os is not an option, may I try to disconnect the front panel from the motherboard, but as I read on the link I posted seems to not work.

So any idea on what is happening???

Comment: Which jack you mean? USB? Audio? Shoulda be a hardware problem. Maybe there is something inside which closes a curcuit.

Comment: I had the same error but it only appeared in Windows, it seems that Windows was mixing up the drive volumes. It was detecting a hard disk drive G: which is one of the partitions on a second hard disk. Well I plugged an external hard disk (with multiple partitions), into the USB 2.0 plug and it gave one partition the letter drive G:. I had added the second hard drive after this fact. I went to the registry and removed the instance of G: it had solved the problem I had.

Comment: As I wrote is the headphone jack, it detect it in the front panel. For the hard drive, my partitions are not on the external hard drive, so driver letter are fixed. However I don't really understand what solved the problem for you